# AJAX passing null string to MVC controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My AJAX call:

```
addClass: "noty-btn",
                            text: "OK",
                            onClick: function($noty) {
                                var applianceId = JSON.stringify(result);
                                $noty.close();
                                $.ajax(
                                {
                                    url: JSON.parse(actionLinks.deletedata),
                                    data: { 'date': datesToDelete, 'stationId': station, 'crewId': crew, 'endDate': enddate, 'checkedCoverStation': true, 'multipleSelected': multiSelect, 'applicationIds': applianceId, 'partialDelete': false},
                                    type: "POST",
                                    success: function() {
                                        resetTable();                                           
                                    }
                                });
                            }
```

My MVC controller Method:

```
public JsonResult DeleteData(string date, int stationId, int crewId, string endDate, bool checkedCoverStation,
            bool multipleSelected, string applianceIds, bool? partialDelete = false)
        {
```

It is passing 'applicanceId' which is a stringified int array to the MVC controller.

I have checked my network tab in chrome dev tools and it is not null in the request, however, when the MVC controller receives it is null.

It needs to be a string representation of an int array because it is used in this way in other parts of the program.

Why is applianceIds always null once it reaches the controller?

Comment: applicationIds != applicianceIds... The field names are not the same.

Comment: @PeterM. Uhh. I sincerely appreciate your help

Comment: @PeterM. Turns out this is a solution-wide issue. Must've been introduced years ago and never fixed. Thanks to your keen eye you've saved me a lot of bother. If I could upvote your comment I would. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo in your code.

The field you've referred to is 'applicationIds' in your JSON, but it's called 'applianceIds' in your MVC controller method.

Fix the typo and you should be good.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. Thanks for your help. I'll accept the answer when I can